# Populist badge description ambiguity

Tags: discussion, badges

The populist badge says "Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x"

Does that mean the highest scoring answer has to have a score of 10 or more, or the accepted answer has to have a score of 10 or more?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258):

> #### Populist
>
> - gold; awarded multiple times
> - Provide an answer that meets all of the following criteria ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886)):
>
>   - it is the highest scoring answer on the question ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6938))
>   - it does *not* have the accepted checkmark
>   - it has a score of 23 or more
>   - it has more than double the score of the accepted answer
>   - the accepted answer has a score of 11 or more
>   - it is not an answer *to your own question* ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221))

Comment: Seems redundant to specify that it has to score 23 or higher, but I suppose it's nice that they did the math for us...:P

Comment: What seems redundant is copying answers from Meta.SE. Now we can have questions about all the badges again. Each answer can look exactly as this one, just copy the description of an appropriate badge :0

Comment: @BartoszKP That is actually pretty normal for a per-site meta, but other metas get much fewer questions. Also, since all these MSE questions used to exist here and now they don't, it feels even more like we're just asking the same things again. But until we get some sort of cross-site duplicate system, there's nothing we can really do about it.

Comment: @animuson Yes, I've read the relevant discussion on this topic :-) Didn't help the feeling that this is just stupid thing to do though ;)

Comment: curious, what happens if the accepted answer is deleted. Would the badge go away? :D

Comment: @Honey The only badges that are ever retracted are tag badges. Otherwise, once you have it, you keep it.

Comment: What's so special about 23? I would understand if it were 42, because it is the answer to everything, but 23?!

Comment: So what if you wrote the question and switch the award checkmark around. Does it hand out the award to the top scoring question even if it's was previously accepted. Also, I have a question with the accepted answer at 17 and mine at 34. Can I downvote the accepted answer and earn the badge? Can I then toggle it back and forth and just collect them repeatedly?

Comment: Apparently no on the downvote thing. I'll try upvoting the accepted answer if I get another organic upvote.

Answer (score 5):

It means the accepted answer has to have a score of more than 10.

So basically your answer has to score more than 22.

If the accepted answer has a score of 11 you have to get to 23, if it has 12 you have to get to 25 (and so on).

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886/59303) for more information

Comment: So the appropriate terminology should be `10 or more`, not `more than 10`, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - no, though I can't find the Meta SE post where this was originally discussed.

Comment: Was it [that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188388/clarify-the-populist-badge-description)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - nope. I'm pretty sure it was on a (admittedly bad) question I raised in the very early days of MSO (as was).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - it was [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886/59303). I got it completely wrong - it was an *answer* of mine.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The wording is correct. "more than 10". 10 on the accepted answer won't get it regardless of your answer votes.